# Using the Qt framework strictly for a personal project I want in my GitHub portfolio

Tags: lgpl, github

I am using the Qt framework for a personal project of mine. Not intended to be sold or used by anyone else. Just a cool project that I want to have in my portfolio. What is required of me under the license if I am to add this to my public GitHub so employers can see it?

Answer (score 1):

As this is a personal project, I will assume you are not using Qt under a commercial, paid for, license but under an open-source, free, license.
The requirements depend on how you incorporate the Qt code in your project and which Qt components you use.

If you use any components that are under the GPL license, rather than the LGPL license, then you must use a GPL-compatible open-source license for your code and it is preferred to use the GPL itself. This is because the combination of all code must be made available under the terms and conditions of the GPL license.

If you only use LGPL-licensed components, then it is very strongly advised that you dynamically link them as libraries into your project. The LGPL requires that it must be possible for the end-user to replace the LGPL code with a different version and that requirement is most easily fulfilled with dynamic linking. Other than that, there are no requirements on your code.